# How do I get a query plan for an ADO query coded in VBA in Access 2016?

Tags: ms-access

I am supporting some VBA code in Access 2016. One of the ADO queries is performing poorly. How do I get a look at the query plan?

Comment: Split database? SQL Server?

Comment: The following link indicates you can use showplan with ADO, but without more info it's hard to make a blanket statement that 'everything is fine': http://microsoft.public.data.ado.narkive.com/uCh48nhH/set-showplan-all-on-in-ado